# How would I label training and testing data for a Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

This is a bit of an abstract question.

I have a group of 28x28 px images from certain people, and I would like to label that data with each person who wrote it. How would I go about labeling it for training and testing? This is my first neural network, and I'm having difficulty finding any tutorials that suit my particular need. It feels like most Data, like MNIST/EMNIST, are already labeled.

Some more info is that I'm using Python 3, and Keras with Tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you know who wrote each image. Then this is a matter of associating that information (the class label) with each image. There are several ways of doing this. Two common approaches are:

### Folder structure

Make a folder for each class (person), and put the images inside.

Folder contents:

```
john/01.png
john/02.png
jane/03.png
susan/...
```

### CSV file

In this case the images can be all in one folder, and then a dedicate Comma-Separated-Values file is used to contain

Folder contents:

```
dataset.csv
images/01.png
images/02.png
images/03.png
images/....
```

dataset.csv contents:

```
filename,person
images/01.png,john
images/02.png,john
images/03.png,jane
...
```

The CSV approach is nice if you have additional data about each file that you want to store. For instance metadata that could be relevant such as who recorded the file, when was it recorded, with what kind of equipment, what locations etc.

Combinations of the two are also possible, of course.